# Using Python, reverse an integer, and tell if palindrome

Tags: python, string, list, program-entry-point, function

Using Python, reverse an integer and determine if it is a palindrome. Here is my definition of reverse and palindrome. Do I have a correct logic?

```
def reverse(num):
    s=len(num)
    newnum=[None]*length
    for i in num:
        s=s-1
        newnum[s]=i
        return newnum

def palindrome(num):
    a=str(num)
    l=len(z)/2
    if a[:1]==a[-1:][::-1]:
        b=True
    else:
        b=False
```

I am having some trouble to write `def main`.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? Does it not work?

Comment: I've done the def main part as well, but it says my input has no len.

Comment: Which part? Post the traceback for the error.

Comment: You're passing an integer to `reverse()`. Integers don't have a "length", only strings and sequences have lengths.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
def palindrome(num):
    return str(num) == str(num)[::-1]
```

Comment: what if it is a negative number?

Comment: @KeonKim I don't think negative numbers can be considered palindromes

Answer (score 20):

Integer numbers don't have len().

Testing if a number is a palindrome is as simple as testing if the number is equal to its reverse (though if you want maximum efficiency you can just compare characters from both ends of the string until you reach the middle).

To find the reverse of an integer you can either do it the hard way (using mod % and integer division // to find each digit and construct the reverse number):

```
def reverse(num):
  rev = 0
  while num > 0:
    rev = (10*rev) + num%10
    num //= 10
  return rev
```

Or the easy way (turning the number into a string, using slice notation to reverse the string and turning it back to an integer):

```
def reverse(num):
  return int(str(num)[::-1])
```

Comment: Your first method is worthy of +1, but it might be useful to point out that we can't reverse a number if it ends with 0. Eg, 1230 would be 321. However, for things like Project Euler where you can be asked to look for palindromes of prime numbers, this methods works fine.

Comment: @Akavall Thank you for the comment, but I'm not sure if you are implying that the concept of reversing a number ending in 0 is undefined (I think 321 == 0321 is a good definition for the reverse of the number 1230), or if my method can't handle such numbers.

If it is the latter, I believe it can. If you are referring to using this to test for palindromicity, numbers ending in 0 can't be palindromes (with the notable exception of 0 itself) and the reverse of such a number according to my definition is always different from the original so we're cool there too, right?

Comment: @pedrosorio, I guess the issue that I was aiming at is that reverse(1230) == reverse(123), since both return 321. But that's an issue that comes up with every method. So I the drawback I was pointing out is not very relevant.

Comment: I have written a [recursive implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38361529/832230) derived in part from this answer.

Comment: I like this one because you can use `reverse(num) == num` to get a T/F bool for "is palindrome?" The exception being if the integer ends (or begins?) with 0, as aforementioned in the comments here.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unreadable one-line recursive implementation based in part on the [answer by pedrosorio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059634/832230).

```
def reverse(i):
    return int(i!=0) and ((i%10)*(10**int(math.log(i,10))) + reverse(i//10))

def is_palindrome(i):
    return i == reverse(i)
```

It works for integer `i ≥ 0`.

Note that `reverse(123) == reverse(1230) == 321`. This is not a problem, considering any nonzero integer that ends with 0 cannot be a palindrome anyway.

Note also that complete reversal of the integer may of course not be necessary to determine if it's a palindrome. The reversal may be implemented so as to be aborted early if the number is determined to not be a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

Long but readable:

```
def palindrome(x):
    a=""
    x=str(x)
    for i in range(len(x),0,-1):
        a+=x[i-1]
        print a
    if a==x:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def revers(num):
    rev = 0
    while num > 0:
        rem = num % 10
        rev = (rev * 10) + rem
        num = num // 10
    return rev
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse an integer and determine if it is a palindrome:

1. Convert integer to string.
2. Use reverse function to reverse the string and join it.
3. Check if reversed number = original number with if else condition.

See code:

```
number = 1221

reverse = ''.join(reversed(str(number)))

print(reverse)

if (int(reverse) == number):
    print("number is Palindrome")
else:
    print("number is not Palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a list for this program, works with strings too.

```
print('Enter Something')
a = list(input())
for i in range ((len(a)),0,-1):
   print (a[i-1],end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

a = raw_input("Enter number:")
n = -1

reverse = 0    
for i in a:
        n += 1
        digit = math.pow(10,n)
        reverse = int(i)*digit + reverse

print int(reverse)  

if int(reverse) == int(a):
        print "Palindrome"
else:
        print ":("
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This code converts int to String and then checks if the string is pallindrome. The advantage is that it is fast, the disadvantage being that it converts int to String thereby compromising with the perfect solution to question.

It handles `negative int` as well.

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        s = str(x)
        if x >=0 :
            if s == s[::-1]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t=int(input("enter nos of test cases= "))
while t>0:
    n=int(input("enter number="))
    rev=0
    while n>0:
        digit=n%10
        rev=rev*10+digit
        n=n//10
    print(rev)
    t-=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
z=input('input number')
if int(z) == int(str(z)[::-1]):
    print('The number is palindrome')
else:
    print('The number is not palindrome')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pal_num(num):
    if num<0:
        print(False)
    elif num == int(str(num)[::-1]):
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

This example quickly takes care of the negative number edge case

Answer (score -2):

I try to come out with this myself.

```
def number():

    n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    return n

def reverse(n):


    total = ""
    while n > 0:
        a = n % 10

        n//= 10


        total+= str(a)

    return total


def palindrome (n):

    total = 0
    while n > 0:
        a = n % 10

        n//= 10


        total+= a

    if total == n:
        x = "This number has a palindrome"

    else:
        x = ""

    return x

n = number()
print (reverse(n))
print (palindrome(n))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
original = raw_input("Enter a no = ")   #original = number entered by user
rev = original[::-1]     #rev = reverse of original by useing scope resolution 
print 'rev of original no =',rev
if original == rev:
    print "no's are equal"
else:
    print "no's are not equal"
```